# How do c# know which method is the constructor

Tags: c#

I've seen people use a Pascal case to define a constructor, they use the same name as the class name. Is it a must?, if not I don't see why c# know that method is the constructor.

Comment: Constructor doesn't have return type + it must have the same name as class

Comment: Did you just answer your own question?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors -- "*A constructor is a method whose name is the same as the name of its type. Its method signature includes only the method name and its parameter list; it does not include a return type.*"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors Constructor has specific syntax. After compilation in MSIL it looks like .ctor

Comment: The constructor has the same name of the class

Comment: Has no **Return Type**.
And **Parameter** may differ.

Comment: Why do you ask? This is by convention, and similar in other languages

Comment: @doctorlove i dont know about constructor since I came from JS. and react has a constructor clearly spelled out. So im abit confuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a must. If you don't provide a constuctor the compiler creates one (known as default constructor) for you and the default values for your members are automatically set.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the constructor is the same as the name of the class. also no return type.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors

Answer (score 1):

In C# methods have both a `return-type` **and** an `identifier` (and parenthesis):

```
[<modifiers>...] <return-type> <identifier>( [<parameters>...] )
{
}
```

e.g.:

```
class Baz
{
    Foo Bar()
    {
    }

    [Obsolete]
    protected internal static async Task<String> GetSomethingAsync( [NotNull] Something else )
    {
    }
}
```

Constructors have **only** a `type-name` specified[^1], and also have parenthesis. The `return-type` must match the parent type name (this is arguably redundant, and newer languages like TypeScript instead use `constructor` as a keyword instead)

```
[<modifiers>...] <type-name>( [<parameters>...] )
{
}
```

e.g.:

```
class Foo
{
    Foo()
    {
    }
}
```

Properties are like methods, but lack parenthesis, and have child blocks named `get` and `set` (or are single-expression bodied members for getter-only properties).

[^1] The C# language specification actually says the text of the constructor's signature is its identifier, not the type-name - but the effect is the same.

Comment: In the second part of your answer you seem to have `return-type` and `identifier` switched?

Comment: Though I like the idea of seeing it as "no name, but only a return type of the class' type" the spec says "no return type, but a name equal to the class' name".

Answer (score 1):

Constructors don't have a return-type and have to have the same name (case-sensitive) as their class.

#### Contructor

```cs
class TestClass
{
    // this is a constructor which has no returntype
    public TestClass() { } 
}
```

#### Mehtod

```cs
class TestClass2
{
    // This is a method as we see at the return type "int".
    public int TestClass2() { return 1; } // This won't compile: "member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type"
}
```

Have a look at this for further info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors